# Load content in div on page load

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I currently have the following:

HTML:

```
<div class="content-class"></div>
```

JQuery Ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on("click", ".content-class", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var post = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            url: 'script.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: { /* some data */ },
            success: function(data) {
                // load content from php file into .content-class
        });
    });
});
```

How do I change that function so that it loads the content from the PHP file into .content-class without having to click it (so that it does it on page load)?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to put the ajax call outside of the event. Do you have many `.content-class` ?

Comment: This is easy, you use a PHP include and include the file in the serverside script, as loading the file with ajax on first pageload makes no sense.

Comment: Can't send data through a PHP include.

Comment: You got that right, the question being what data do you have to send to the server on pageload that you don't already have access to on the serverside ?

Answer (score 3):

Just remove the click event listener and do the ajax straight away:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'script.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { /* some data */ },
        success: function(data) {
            // load content from php file into .content-class
            $('.content-class').html(data);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

as PSL said, just move the ajax call outside of click event handler:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'script.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { /* some data */ },
        success: function(data) {
            // load content from php file into .content-class
    });
});
```